# Any way to control which audio channel AVSpeechSynthesizer outputs to?

Tags: ios, audio, avspeechsynthesizer, tvos

I would like to use AVSpeechSynthesizer to output sound on only one audio channel of a multi-channel surround sound setup. For example, in a 5.1 system, I would like it to output on just the right-surround channel.

Right now I have:

```
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "This is the right channel")
    synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)
```

...however it outputs on both the left and right channels.

Comment: @Mei, I have to do the same thing... Did you got any solution for this?

Comment: No, I did not. My solution was to abandon using the speech synthesizer and instead use pre-recorded audio that I filtered to the correct channel using Audacity. Here's a YouTube video on how to extract the sound to the correct channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu37UaVlLJE