# Hi, Is there a way for the AVSpeech Synthesizer to play audio using either channels while playing audio using a headset?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avspeechsynthesizer

What i need is to play audio using either the left or the right channel alone. 
I know that AVAudioPlayer can play the audio using either channel using the pan property. 
If AVSpeechSynthesizer has no way to accomplish this, is it possible to play the utterance using AVAudioPlayer so that the channels can be controlled? 
If I could somehow get the NSURL of the AVSpeechUtterance and play that using AVAudioPlayer?

Only previous similar question : [Any way to control which audio channel AVSpeechSynthesizer outputs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558183/any-way-to-control-which-audio-channel-avspeechsynthesizer-outputs-to) I found is not answered and I have came up empty trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this using the `outputChannels` property of `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. Apple hasn't posted any documentation for this, but it works the same way as the `channelAssignments` property of `AVAudioPlayer`. This returns a human-readable list of available channels:

```
- (NSArray *)getAudioChannelNames {
    // return the name of each channel in each connected audio port
    // examples: Headphones Left/Right, Speaker, DUO-CAPTURE 1/2
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *route = [session currentRoute];
    NSArray *outputPorts = [route outputs];
    NSMutableArray *channels = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *outputPort in outputPorts) {
        for (AVAudioSessionChannelDescription *channel in outputPort.channels) {
            [channels addObject:channel.channelName];
        }
    }
    return channels;
}
```

You or the user can select a channel name to use. Then this sets the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to use that channel:

```
- (void)setSpeechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)speechSynthesizer toChannels:(NSArray *)channelNames {
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *route = [session currentRoute];
    NSArray *outputPorts = [route outputs];
    NSMutableArray *channelDescriptions = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *channelName in channelNames) {
        for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *outputPort in outputPorts) {
            for (AVAudioSessionChannelDescription *channel in outputPort.channels) {
                if ([channel.channelName isEqualToString:channelName]) {
                    [channelDescriptions addObject:channel];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ([channelDescriptions count]) {
        speechSynthesizer.outputChannels = channelDescriptions;
    }
}
```

Comment: speechSynthesizer.outputChannels supports from iOS 10.* Is there any option to do that in iOS 8.0

Comment: every time i set output channels like that the array of channels is always empty. Any clues how come? ( i use Swift and ios 10)

Comment: @zo_chu Do you mean the result of `getAudioChannelNames` is empty? Are you using `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute` for your audio session? I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: i've figured it out. i wanted to route the synth to different audio route (build in speaker when headset is connected) and that's not supported. when i pick channels from current route it works.